# Remote Kernel and CUDALink

Tags: remote-access, cudalink

I have setup a remote kernel on my Mac, which connects to a more powerful Linux 64Bit Desktop. Mathematica is setup fine on the Linux machine. CUDA is also working fine and `NVIDIA_DRIVER _LIBRARY_PATH` and `CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH` are set just fine, although they are not the default paths.

When I connect from my mac using the mathematica frontend the connection via remote kernel is initialized fine and I can do my calculations, but CUDA is not working. Taking a closer look shows, that the paths mentioned above are not set properly any more. This can be seen by checking GPUTools`Internal`\$NVIDIADriverLibraryPath and GPUTools`Internal`\$CUDALibraryPath.

On the linux machine I set the paths manually using /etc/profile file. It is my understanding that the remote kernel being setup to call the `math` command should just start a mathematica terminal session. Starting mathematica via terminal using the `math` command on the linux machine works just fine and has the paths setup correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I modified the /usr/local/bin/math file on the linux machine to set the `NVIDIA_DRIVER_LIBRARY_PATH` and the `CUDA_LIBRARY_PATH`, which set the paths correctly. I still don't know why setting it in /etc/profile works for the linux machine but not via remote kernel usage. If someone knows I'd like to hear why.

Comment: If I remember correctly then /etc/profile is for settings of interactive sessions and might not be read when just executing the script /usr/local/bin/math. You could either try /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc (assuming your default shell is bash). I think there might also be differences in initialization whether you explicitly call bash or whether you call justsh, so it might also depend on the shebang in /usr/local/bin/math.  I suggest to check the documentation of your shell and linux distribution as I think these things might even slightly differ for various distributions and shells...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's exactly what I suspected. But I was not really sure if I was missing something else.